# CSS @media doing strange things

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a HTML element:

```html
<div id=... class="pie-chart-container"></div>
```

I'm trying to change the size of this `div` depending on whether media type is `screen` or `print`.
Originally, my CSS styles defined the size of the screen version, and then `@media print` to change the size of the printed version. This wasn't working as I expected, so I swapped around the styles to define the print version, and then use `@media screen` to control the size of the screen version, as follows:

```css
.pie-chart-container {
    width: 20cm;
    height: 25cm;
    margin: auto;
}

@media screen {
    .pie-chart-container {
        width: 80vw;
        height: 100vh;
    }
}
```

However, this also seems to be behaving strangely, as when I change the width and height *inside* the media query, the dimensions of the `div` are changed in the *print* version (and also the screen version). Changing the width and height in the first selector, outside the media query, also has an effect on the printed version, but not in the same way as changing the values inside the media query - changing the values in the selector outside the query seems to increase the space the `div` takes up, without changing the size of the elements inside the `div` very much, although the elements inside do move around a little.

If anyone has any knowledge on what/why this is happening, I would be very greatful if you shared it.

**Note**: I am using Chrome's print preview to view the effects of the styles on the printed version.

*Update*: This `div` contains a Google Chart, so there is a massive amount of code inside. The top few levels look like this:

```html
<div id="donutchart2" class="pie-chart-container">
  <div style="position: relative">
    <div dir="ltr" style="position: relative; width: 1138px; height: 653px">
      <div
        aria-label="A chart."
        style="
          position: absolute;
          left: 0px;
          top: 0px;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        "
      >
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div
      aria-hidden="true"
      style="
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 663px;
        left: 1148px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
      "
    >
    </div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This sounds like the `div` children are impacting the size (e.g., set to 80vw when inside content is wider than that). Please post code of children or whatever elements are inside as well.

Comment: '@media mediaType and screenWidth ( max-width / min-width )' are essentials to make your media query work, for example '@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){ // code goes here }'

Comment: @mr_joncollette I've updated the post with some of the code from inside the `div`, cheers.

Comment: @VenkateshChitluri I added a min-width to the query, but changing values inside the query still affects the printed version unfortunately

Comment: for me, the width and height are behaving as per the style-rule... following the @media strictly. https://ibb.co/Rv9Ws5b